# nxfilter does not start in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to start nxfilter in docker with docker-compose but I have some problem with volumes. I have created the directories on my raspberry pi but when I run the .yml file, an error appears.
this is my .yml

```
version: '3.5'

 services:

 nxfilter:

  container_name: nxfilter
  hostname: nxfilter
  image: deepwoods/nxfilter:latest
  tty: true
  environment:
    TZ: "Europe/Madrid"
  volumes:
    - ./persistent-volumes/nxfilter/confdir:/nxfilter/conf
    - ./persistent-volumes/nxfilter/dbdir:/nxfilter/db
    - ./persistent-volumes/nxfilter/logdir:/nxfilter/log
  ports:
    - 53:53/udp
    - 19004:19004/udp
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
    - 19002-19004:19002-19004
  restart: unless-stopped
```

but when I run docker-compose I get the following error

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/javieradguard/dockerPrivacidad# docker-compose - 
f docker-compose-nxfilter.yml up
Attaching to nxfilter
nxfilter  | Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
nxfilter  |     at nxd.Main.<init>(Unknown Source)
nxfilter  |     at nxd.Main.main(Unknown Source)
nxfilter  | Exception in thread "Thread-0" 
java.lang.NullPointerException
nxfilter  |     at nxd.n.run(Unknown Source)
nxfilter exited with code 0
```

If I remove the volumes from the container, it starts correctly, so I think the problem may come from there. I have tried giving 777 permissions to the directories, but it didn't work.
Any ideas?? I'm working on a raspberry pi 4 with raspberry pi OS lite 64 bit

Comment: You seem to have included image files in place of the Compose YAML file and the Compose output.  [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to replace the images with plain text?  It looks like the second picture might be a PNG-rendered Java exception; can you also make sure to include the source code that leads to this exception?

Comment: already answered here https://github.com/DeepWoods/nxfilter-docker/issues/1